# C++, Inheriting template nested class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

Trying to get `tensor_ref<A>::result` visible in tensor_view.

```
template<class A, class Range, class = void>
struct tensor_view
    : detail::tensor_ref<A>,
    const_tensor_view<A, Range, tensor_view<A, Range> >
{
    using detail::tensor_ref<A>::result;
```

...

```
template<class A>
struct tensor_ref<A, typename same_rank<A,N>::enable>
    : const_tensor_ref<A>
{
    template<class I>
    struct result {
        typedef typename traits<A>::reference type;
    };
```

> error: no class template named "result" in "struct tensor::tensor_view<...

What gives?

Comment: Cut and paste snipits are a waste of time as most of the code we need is missing. If you want more than educated guesses give a compilable piece of code with the full error message. English text may be nice but it is really only for you the rest of us are quite fluent at using a compiler.

Comment: Tried declaring an object of type detail::tensor_ref<A>::result, rather than using, using ?

Comment: @Martin  Not easy to do so.  The templates span 4 files and are quiet large.

Comment: @Dumb Result is template and needs  be inherited as such

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't work and it [*isn't* intended](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_closed.html#109) to make it work for any further revision of C++.

So you cannot have that using declaration - use the ordinary `tensor_view::template result` way when using it, instead.

Comment: This is an answer for my answer?

Comment: @nice it's intended as being an answer to the question. It however also happens to show your take at answering it is wrong (edit: *was* wrong in your first version, now that you have the link in your answer too it's not wrong anymore).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how to go about it the way you're trying, or if it's even possible, but you should be able to get something equivelent by doing this:

```
// using detail::tensor_ref<A>::result;
template < typename I > struct result : detail::tensor_ref<I> {};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to prefix it with typename, as it's a dependent type.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you never specify what `I` is when attempting to instantiate a `result<I>`.

For example:

```
detail::tensor_ref<A>::result;
```

Should be:

```
detail::tensor_ref<A>::result< /* Some type */ >;
```

That said, it looks like you can get rid of the line:

```
template<class I>
```

Because in the snippet you've provided, `I` is completely unused.